# environment var not found on SuSe init.d script at boot

Tags: tomcat, java, boot, service, environment-variables

I've got a `/etc/init.d/tomcat1` script which runs on boot on rc levels 3 and 5. This script calls `/usr/local/tomcat1/bin/startup.sh` on start.

Although I can manually execute `/usr/local/tomcat1/bin/startup.sh` from console, on boot I get the following in `/var/log/boot.msg`:

```
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

After that I added the following in `/etc/init.d/boot.local`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java"
```

But I still get the same message about `JAVA_HOME` missing.

What I ended up doing is modifying `/usr/local/tomcat1/bin/catalina.sh` and hardcoding the following:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java"
```

Tomcat now does start on boot but I know that hardcoding this in the catalina.sh script is not good.

So the question is, how can I set/export `JAVA_HOME` so that it's readable from scripts running on boot?

thanks

Comment: Did you set `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Why did you put it everywhere but not in `/usr/local/tomcat1/bin/startup.sh`?!

Answer (score 1):

Put your changes in `/etc/profile.local` so they load for all users.  In this case, putting
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java` in that file should be sufficient.

`/etc/boot.local` runs after all other scripts for a given runlevel, so changes you make there won't be seen by other init scripts.  For your example above to work, you would need to put the following in `boot.local`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
/usr/local/tomcat1/bin/startup.sh
```

i.e. set the environment variable, then launch the startup script.